# Suppose $f$ and $g$ grow without bound and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f - g = \infty$. Can we conclude that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{g}{f} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

In [a previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961202/suppose-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-fracfxgx-1-is-lim-f-g-0) it was made clear to the OP that for most $f$ and $g$,
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} f/g = 1 \quad  \not\!\!\!\!\implies \quad \lim_{x\to \infty} f-g = 0.
$$

Here I am asking a similar question:

Let $f(x),g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Is it true that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) - g(x) \implies \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = 0 \ \ ?
$$

As an example, let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \log x$. Observe that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} x - \log x = \infty \qquad \text{and} \qquad \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\log x}{x} \overset{LH}= 0
$$
by L'Hopital's rule.

I haven't been able to find a counterexample yet and I haven't I been able to prove it that it is true. One idea is to somehow use the fact that
$$
f- g = f(1-g/f).
$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Gotchya sounds good. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Just take any $g$ and define $f = 2g$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Take $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=x$.

---

For more counterexamples, simply observe that $g(x)=O(f(x))$ does not imply $g(x)=o(f(x))$ and there are many examples of $g(x)=O(f(x))$ with $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-g(x)=\infty$.

Comment: Ah nice. lol that's embarrassing. Thank you!

Comment: @JazzGuitar7: You are welcome. No worries. I think it is better to post the follow-up in another post.

Answer (score 0):

It can be rewritten $f=g+h$ with $h\to+\infty$.

Note that since $f,g,h$ all go to $+\infty$ then all three are positive at infinity.

In particular $1=g/f+h/f$ so $$0\le g/f=1-\overbrace{h/f}^{\ge 0}\le 1$$

Meaning that $g=O(f)$ and not necessarily $o(f)$ as you supposed.

The upper bound is effectively reached for $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x-\sqrt{x}$ for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)= 3x-x\sin x$ Then $$f(x)-g(x)=x[2-\sin x]\ge x$$ and $${g(x)\over f(x)}={1\over 3-\sin x}$$ so the limit of the ratio does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for $g/f$ to have a limit, and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{g}{f}=1$. For example, $f(x)=x^2+x$; $g(x)=x^2$.